# Regarding jdbc Realm

Tags: jakarta-ee

I want to do login using form based authentication. i have been followed all steps for creating jdbc realm but run time error is coming. error is like-SEVERE: SEC1111: Cannot load group for JDBC realm user [pqr]. WARNING: Web login failed: Login failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException:  Security Exception

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem when I have user and group table name in mysql.
This is restricted keywords in some databases and should be changed to another one.

Change group to grouptable and user to usertable (or something like this).

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by a database error. E.g. invalid column name. You should increase the log level for security:

Assuming you are using Glassfish v3:
In the glassfish admin console (http://localhost:4848/) under "Configuration > Logger Settings > Log Levels" set "javax.enterprise.system.core.security" to "FINEST". Then try to login again and have a look at the log. In my setup the logfile is here:
glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log

If you cannot resolve your issue with the help of the log, post the log output here, so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article about jdbc security realm in glassfish:
http://java-cookbook.blogspot.com/2011/02/jdbc-security-realm-with-glassfish-and.html